# In an event-loop based server (FastAPI), are async/await functions atomic?

Tags: python, async-await, concurrency, fastapi

I've read so much about async/await, co-routines, and single-threaded, non-blocking servers. But I'm still not %100 about this situation, and I need to be.

I'm running [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/).

I have an endpoint:

```
@router.get("/get-next-id")
async def get_next_id():
    return await id_module.get_next_id()
```

It calls (and awaits) ths async function in 'id_module' (I know there are safer ways to generate a sequential ID. This is just an example to demonstrate a possible concurrency issue.):

```
async def get_next_id():
    next_id = None
    with open("id_flat_file.json") as serialized_data_file:
        id_dict = json.load(serialized_data_file)
        next_id = id_dict["id"] + 1

    with open("id_flat_file.json", 'w') as serialized_data_file:
        json.dump({"id": next_id}, serialized_data_file)

    return next_id
```

Questions:

- Is `get_next_id()` guaranteed to run on the main thread of the event loop?
- If so, is it thread safe? I.e., is it atomic to the main thread? Could it ever be 'paused' and interrupted by the main thread (which could also be running the same code for another request)? I.e., in my code, do I have to worry about a race condition and somehow otherwise protect (lock) against that?

Comment: Why would you think async / await does anything for thread safety? Try adding a time.sleep somewhere in the middle, add some printing before and after and then call the method twice and see what happens, if you only see one pre-print or two.

Comment: @luk2302 it's not just about async/await. It's also about single-threaded, non-blocking servers. If there's only one thread (the "main thread"), then as long as a function can't be interrupted, it's thread safe. I have reasons to think this is true, and I've already done the test you suggest, which seems to support what I think. But, in this case, I need to be %100 certain, and so I'd like to hear what others have to say, and ideally get a reference to some documentation (which I've searched for but haven't found) that makes it crystal clear.

Comment: In this specific case with an API server; in almost every case you'll run multiple workers and instances of your server - so it's not really about thread safety, but more about how you handle multiple simultaneous request for the same resource and functionality. But since you're never giving up your processing time in your async function, no other code will run on the event loop until you do so (await/async isn't threading). https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading might be a decent reference.

Comment: @MatsLindh many thanks. "...since you're never giving up your processing time in your async function, no other code will run on the event loop until you do so..." really nice to hear someone else say this. I'm not (yet) running multiple workers or instances, but I'm finally realizing that I have to design for it, and that it presents similar concurrency problems (to threading) in terms of shared resources, regardless of the event loop. I know coroutines aren't threading, I just have never really grokked the single-threaded non-blocking model.